How to combine headers from different channels with distinct payload types into a single message for further processing in Spring Integration?
I'm new to Java and Spring/Spring Integration and I'm having an issue with message channels and aggregators. I'm trying to aggregate headers from two different channels into a single message object or list, but I'm not sure of the best approach. Currently, my output channel only processes one message at a time.
Here's my current setup:
public class IntCon {

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel inputChannel1() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel inputChannel2() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow vinylArchiveFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from("inputChannel1")
                .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                    List<VinylRecord> records = (List<VinylRecord>) payload;
                    VinylRecord lastVinyl = records.getLast();

                    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(lastVinyl)
                            .setHeader("lastVinyl", true)
                            .copyHeaders(headers)
                            .build();
                })
                .channel("outputChannel")
                .get();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow cdArchiveFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from("inputChannel2")
                .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                    List<CdRecord> records = (List<CdRecord>) payload;
                    CdRecord lastCD = records.getLast();

                    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(lastCD)
                            .setHeader("lastCD", true)
                            .copyHeaders(headers)
                            .build();
                })
                .channel("outputChannel")
                .get();
    }
}

Here is a very basic version of what I also have implemented, but it currently only accepts one message at a time and doesn't process both, even though they’re both confirmed on the output channel.
@Aggregator(inputChannel = "outputChannel", outputChannel = "willDefineLater")
public Message<?> aggregate(final List<Message<?>> messages) {
    boolean isLastVinyl = false;
    boolean isLastCD = false;

    // Loop over the incoming messages
    for (Message<?> message : messages) {
        // Store the message for later
        messageStore.addMessage(message);

        // Check the message for the headers
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(message.getHeaders().get("lastVinyl"))) {
            isLastVinyl = true; // Set isLastVinyl to true
        }
        
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(message.getHeaders().get("lastCD"))) {
            isLastCD = true; // Set isLastCD to true
        }
    }

    return ...; 
}



What I'm looking for is a way to have both those headers in the same message coming into the aggregator so that when both conditions are true I can run other methods already defined. How can I modify my setup to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Looks like you are missing a fundamental feature of the aggregator - correlation.
The aggregator gathers messages with the same correlation key into one group, and then release that group when release condition is met.
Please, make yourself familiar with its model: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/aggregator.html.
By default, it looks for a IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID header, but apparently you are missing it and respective IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_SIZE in your input messages.

Thanks for the input and guidance! I'll take a look into these resources

I used the .setHeader("demoCorrelation", true) method on both incoming flows to successfully aggregate different payload types into a single message. The flow checks headers with .correlationStrategy and releases the group once it reaches a certain size, so thanks for your help!
However, in a more complex application, this approach didn’t work as expected. Are there situations where .setHeader("randomHeader", value) might have issues aggregating different payload types?

You might just miss to set that header somewhere. You may also consider to use some different CorrelationStrategy, based not on the header, but some payload part or so. Either way, the aggregator cannot do its job with a well-established correlation details for the particular scenario.
